# Google FCM POST request to send a broadcast message and handle it also in the background

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, notifications

I'm developing an app, that when a notification is received, it need to open it up, extract the payload inside and put it on a CardView
But, i have two problems right now, the first one is how to properly do a POST request, do i need another separate app to do it? I mean, written for only do POST, or are there other tools?

Because with the FCM dashboard, i can only send

> Notification messages

While

> Data messages

aren't handled yet by FCM

The second problem is how to handle the notification while the app is killed or in the backgroud. I've alredy verified with Notification messages, they come even with the app being killed or on the background, but `onMessageReceived` do not trigger on those cases.

This is my `onMessageReceived`:

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService  {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Intent sendMessage = new Intent();
    sendMessage.setAction("com.blablabla.blablabla.MessaggingService");
    sendMessage.putExtra("REMOTE_PAYLOAD", remoteMessage.getData().toString()); 
    sendMessage.putExtra("REMOTE_DATA", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    sendBroadcast(sendMessage);
}
```

}

And this is how i handle it by a Fragment: ( I need fragment, a Navigation Drawer is present)

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
TextView mTextView;

BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mTextView.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("REMOTE_DATA"));
    }

    public MessageReceiver(){

    }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View view =  lf.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.info_text);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.blablabla.blablabla.MessaggingService");
    mReceiver = new MessageReceiver();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    return view;

}
```

}